# Why is this question "primarily opinion-based?"

Tags: support, specific-question

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212383/in-the-movie-looper-how-does-this-happen) was put on hold as "primarily opinion based." I'm asking about the logic of time-loops in the movie, and received an answer as such. How is that opinion-based?

Comment: For the record, it's also a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24366/doesnt-the-end-of-looper-create-a-time-paradox/24370#24370 since time travel is explained to death on that question.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not, and has been reopened.**

I fail to see why it was closed in the first place, but it has now been reopened.

For the record, I've noticed an increase in close votes recently for questions that we may not have an exact canon answer for. However, we have established here on meta that such questions are not POB just because there isn't a definite canon answer. Your question seems to have been among the unlucky group of questions that actually gets closed. Fortunately, it's been reopened now.

Comment: I’ve seen a large increase in POB questions being reopened or trying to be reopened because people think we don’t know answers can apply to literally everything. I think your opinion on whether or not this is the case can be left out of the discussion for a specific question.

Comment: Now I want to cast a "sideways vote" for "I disagree with you in principle, but not necessarily in this case, but also this entire discussion is now moot anyway."

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It seems strange you should say that when you yourself were one of the reopen voters on this question.

Comment: @Randal'Thor why? One case is different to the whole general practice. And that’s why I left my comment, for this specific question I agree it shouldn’t be closed however I disagree with the answerers opinion on the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the question does not ask for opinions (either explicitly or implicitly) and it can be answered objectively, it would seem to not be Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: A long comment discussion apparently based on a misunderstanding of this answer has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93775/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-why-is-this-question-primarily-opinion-based).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I didn't *misunderstand this answer*, I disagreed with it.

Comment: @Valorum Well, your comments seemed to be based on a misunderstanding of it, namely that it was equating "OP asserts that a question can be answered definitively" with POB.